# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o389.parquet when trying to write rdd dataframe as parquet files on local directory

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, typeerror, parquet

I am trying to write a dataframe to parquet files on my local directory using the following code within a Jupyter notebook:

```
rdd1 = rdd.coalesce(partitions)

schema1 = StructType([StructField('date', DateType()), StructField('open', FloatType()), StructField('high', FloatType()),
           StructField('low', FloatType()),StructField('close', FloatType()),StructField('adj_close', FloatType()),
           StructField('volume', FloatType()), StructField('stock', StringType())])

rddDF = spark.createDataFrame(rdd1,schema=schema1)

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec", "gzip")

rddDF.write.parquet("C:/Users/"User"/Documents/File/Output/rddDF")
```

I am getting the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-7b2aeb627267> in <module>
    16 
    17 #rddDF.to_parquet("C:/Users/Sabihah/Documents/6. Processing Big Data/Output/rddDF")
---> 18 rddDF.write.parquet("C:/Users/Sabihah/Documents/6. Processing Big Data/Output/rddDF")
    19 #rddDF.write.format("parquet").save("C:/Users/Sabihah/Documents/6. Processing Big Data/Output/rddDF")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in parquet(self, path, mode, partitionBy, compression)
   883             self.partitionBy(partitionBy)
   884         self._set_opts(compression=compression)
--> 885         self._jwrite.parquet(path)
   886 
   887     def text(self, path, compression=None, lineSep=None):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
  1307 
  1308         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1309         return_value = get_return_value(
  1310             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  1311 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
   109     def deco(*a, **kw):
   110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
   112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
   113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
   324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
   325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
   327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
   328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o48.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
   at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:496)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:251)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:110)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:110)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:106)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:481)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:82)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:481)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:457)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:106)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:93)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:91)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:128)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:848)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:355)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:781)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
   at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
   at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
   at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
   at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
   at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
   at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) (DESKTOP-JBUENQG executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Spark\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 619, in main
 File "C:\Spark\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 611, in process
 File "C:\Spark\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 259, in dump_stream
   vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
 File "C:\Spark\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\util.py", line 74, in wrapper
   return f(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\Sabihah\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 682, in prepare
   verify_func(obj)
 File "C:\Users\Sabihah\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1411, in verify
   verify_value(obj)
 File "C:\Users\Sabihah\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1398, in verify_struct
   raise TypeError(new_msg("StructType can not accept object %r in type %s"
TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'close' in type <class 'str'>

   at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:545)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:703)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:685)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:498)
   at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:286)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$16(FileFormatWriter.scala:229)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2352)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2351)
   at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
   at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
   at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2351)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
   at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2591)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2533)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2522)
   at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:898)
   at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2214)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:218)
   ... 42 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Spark\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 619, in main
 File "C:\Spark\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 611, in process
 File "C:\Spark\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 259, in dump_stream
   vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
 File "C:\Spark\Spark\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\util.py", line 74, in wrapper
   return f(*args, **kwargs)
 File "C:\Users\Sabihah\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py", line 682, in prepare
   verify_func(obj)
 File "C:\Users\Sabihah\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1411, in verify
   verify_value(obj)
 File "C:\Users\Sabihah\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\types.py", line 1398, in verify_struct
   raise TypeError(new_msg("StructType can not accept object %r in type %s"
TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'close' in type <class 'str'>

   at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:545)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:703)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$3.read(PythonRunner.scala:685)
   at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:498)
   at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491)
   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:286)
   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$16(FileFormatWriter.scala:229)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
   at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
   ... 1 more
```

I've checked all my system variables:
Hadoop_home, Java_home, Spark_home, Scala_home, Pyspark_python, Pyspark_driver_python.

I've installed Spark v3.2 with Hadoop v2.7 and Scala 2.12.4, updated to v2.12.10.
I'm using Python 3.8 within my notebook.

I've tried downgrading to Python 3.7, but that didn't fix the problem.

I'm not sure what else to try in order to fix this error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
I tried to fix the datatypes but the error persisted.

I then made the following change to the way I created the Dataframe:

```
rddDF = spark.createDataFrame([rdd1],schema=schema1)
```

That removed the TypeError:

```
StructType can not accept object 'close' in type <class 'str'>
```

and my error now shows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-ec6844f98c97> in <module>
     16 
     17 #rddDF.to_parquet("C:/Users/Sabihah/Documents/6. Processing Big Data/Output/rddDF")
---> 18 rddDF.write.parquet("C:/Users/Sabihah/Documents/6. Processing Big Data/Output/rddDF")
     19 #rddDF.write.format("parquet").save("C:/Users/Sabihah/Documents/6. Processing Big Data/Output/rddDF")

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in parquet(self, path, mode, partitionBy, compression)
    883             self.partitionBy(partitionBy)
    884         self._set_opts(compression=compression)
--> 885         self._jwrite.parquet(path)
    886 
    887     def text(self, path, compression=None, lineSep=None):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1307 
   1308         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1309         return_value = get_return_value(
   1310             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1311 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o389.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:481)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:481)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:457)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:128)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:848)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:382)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:781)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1420)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:601)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1972)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.getAllCommittedTaskPaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:334)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJobInternal(FileOutputCommitter.java:404)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitJob(FileOutputCommitter.java:377)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.commitJob(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:48)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitJob(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$20(FileFormatWriter.scala:240)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeTakenMs(Utils.scala:605)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:240)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: `StructType can not accept object 'close' in type <class 'str'>` <= did you see this error?

Comment: Thanks, @GaëlJ. Tried to fix that but with no success.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the new error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o389.parquet.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:496)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125)
```

The way I solved the problem on my Windows machine was by adding Hadoop's "bin" directory (in the directory specified by HADOOP_HOME) to the PATH variable.

When my HADOOP_HOME didn't exist, or wasn't pointed to the right spot, I got one error (that escapes me now). But after I fixed that, I ran into the one you experienced. After trying to use 7 different versions of Hadoop files (winutils.exe and hadoop.dll), the "path" problem occurred to me. This is the sort of mess when an OSS project depends on a bunch of other ones, and they all have their own way of resolving dependencies.

I ran this from an elevated Powershell prompt, restarted my VsCode instance (which is where I run my Jupyter Notebooks), and I was able to save parquet files.

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "$env:PATH;$env:HADOOP_HOME\bin", 'Machine')
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error:

```
TypeError: StructType can not accept object 'close' in type <class 'str'>
```

It seems that the `close` column should be defined as `StringType` and not `FloatType` as you did.

Comment: Thanks, @Gabip. Tried changing the datatype but the error persists.

Comment: Do you get the same error? Maybe there is another TypeError for other fields as well?

Comment: It's not exactly the same error. The full error is in the updated question.

Comment: You can't say that `error persists` if you get a different error. People should not guess what happens on your local env.

Comment: In any case, this is totally a different issue and it is probably related to the old hadoop version that you use. Try to upgrade to 2.9 or 3+

Comment: Apologies, @Gabip. I was getting the same error after changing the data type, and had to do so for more than one column because it persisted, then I found another way to do it and updated the question.

Comment: I'm currently using Hadoop 3.2

Comment: I meant hadoop version (which currently you use 2.7) and not spark. Spark 3+ is not compatible with such an old hadoop version.

Answer (score 0):

Is probably that you are using windows, so you must have to download the winutils repo from github and add the bin path of the Hadoop version you are using to the environment variables.
Link of the repo: https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils